# Passenger standalone can't start server after enabling SSL on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a Rails project up on an EC2 server at AWS. To deploy it, I followed this Passenger tutorial to the letter:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/standalone/oss/deploy_app_main.html

Everything worked fine. Then I followed this Passenger tutorial to get SSL working:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html

My Passengerfile and nginx conf file look the same as the ones in the link (with the paths replaced to point to the correct files). But now, best I can gather, the nginx server isn't starting when I use the command `sudo bundle exec passenger start`.

I found this on the nginx log:

```
May 29 18:46:20 ip-172-31-38-233 systemd[18230]: nginx.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
May 29 18:46:20 ip-172-31-38-233 systemd[18230]: nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
```

Which doesn't make sense to me as nginx was working fine before the SSL certificates. Note I'm using Passenger standalone, so I'm not managing nginx myself.